# which function can replace the deprecated function thrust::detail::backend::dereference In thrust 1.7

Tags: cuda, thrust

I'm a newbie to CUDA and thrust, I downloaded a GPU BVH building code from google code. But the code is written under older version of CUDA and thrust. Now, I'm using the latest CUDA 5.5 with thrust 1.7. It seems that the derefrence function has been deprecated, so I wonder how can I rewrite the following code in the latest CUDA and thrust

```
typename std::iterator_traits<Output_iterator>::value_type value = def_value;
for (uint32 i = begin; i < end; ++i)
  value = op( value, thrust::detail::backend::dereference( in_values + i ) );
thrust::detail::backend::dereference( out_values, leaf_id ) = value;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's in_values and out_values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to just dereference the iterators directly with a more recent version of Thrust:

`typename std::iterator_traits<Output_iterator>::value_type value = def_value;
for (uint32 i = begin; i < end; ++i)
  value = op( value, in_values[i]  );
out_values[leaf_id] = value;`

Answer (score 1):

Probably the simplest solution is to download the version of Thrust you need from [GitHub](http://thrust.github.io) and compile directly.

Using Thrust's internal functions is not a good idea. The API shouldn't change without good reason, but the internals could change at any time.

Comment: The problem seems to be that the library he's attempting to build used functionality from Thrust's internal implementation which no longer exists in the most recent version.

Comment: @JaredHoberock: I agree, I'm suggesting he could download the older version of Thrust and use that version instead of the version (1.7) that is supplied with CUDA 5.5.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, that's a good idea. There're other similar problems caused by the same reason. I should use an older version of Thrust!